# Computer keeps shutting off and turning back on

Tags: power-supply, power, repair

This just started out today. My computer will be working fine one moment, and then it will completely shut off instantly (No windows message or anything), and turn back on in the next instant.

After that, it will not go past my BIOS loading screen unless I reboot it again. (I have seen a quick message about ASUS Anti-Surge kicking in as it detected a power surge in the previous boot.)

I've checked the temps of my CPU and GPU, and they don't seem to be overheating. (CPU at about 52 and GPU at about 32).

Also, just a couple minutes ago, 2 of my 3 monitors randomly shut off and turned back on. The computer stayed running though.

I'm thinking it's the Power supply, but the monitors shutting off are making me think potential video card.

How can I be sure what the problem is?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, there's no particularly cheap way to test things, as the diagnostic for this is to swap parts out or try them on another machine.

This does sound a lot like power issues, and I too would first suspect a bad powersupply. You can verify the monitors by plugging them into another computer - if they seem to work just fine, then I'd suspect the graphics card isn't getting enough power, or the graphics card is damaged (in that order).

Best idea would be to test with a different power supply and see if the issues go away. Also, I wouldn't trust the existing power supply to keep your components safe unless you can rule out that the power supply isn't causing the issues.